# Prove that $\Phi$ is a lower semicontinuous functional.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces, semicontinuous-functions

**QUESTION:** Let $(X, \|.\|)_X$ be a Banach space and $Y\subset X$ a subspace, which is itself a Banach space endowed with a norm $\|.\|_Y$ such that $\|y\|_X\leq \|x\|_Y$ for every $y\in Y$. Assume that $J:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a functional on $X$ such that $J|_{(Y, \|.\|)_Y}$ is continuous and satisfies:

1. $J$ has a directional derivative $\langle J'(u), v\rangle$ at each $u\in X$ through any direction $v\in Y$.
2. For fixed $u\in X$, the function $\langle J'(u), v\rangle$ is linear in $v\in Y$, and, for fixed $v\in Y$, the function $\langle J'(u), v \rangle$ is continuous in $u\in X$.

Let $K$ be a compact metric space, $K_0\subset K$ a closed subset and $\gamma_0: K_0\longrightarrow (Y, \|.\|_Y)$ a continuous map. Consider that $$\Gamma=\left\{\gamma:K\longrightarrow (Y, \| . \|) : \gamma\; \text{is continuous and} \; \gamma|_{K_0}=\gamma_0\right\}$$ is a complete metric space endowed with the uniform distance $$d_{\Gamma}(\gamma_1, \gamma_2)=\displaystyle\max_{t\in K} \|\gamma_1(t)-\gamma_2(t)\|_Y,$$ with $\gamma_1, \gamma_2\in \Gamma$. Defining, $\Phi$ on $\Gamma$ by setting $\Phi(\gamma)=\displaystyle\max_{t\in K} J(\gamma(t))$ prove that $\Phi$ is a lower semicontinuous functional.

**MY ATTEMPT:** I understood that $\Phi$ as defined above is like

\begin{alignat*}{2}
 \Phi:\Gamma &\longrightarrow  X &\\
  \gamma &\longmapsto & \Phi(\gamma):(Y, \Vert\cdot\Vert_{Y}) &\longrightarrow\mathbb{R} \\
  &&J&\longmapsto\Phi(\gamma)=\displaystyle\max_{t\in K} J(\gamma(t)),\; \forall \gamma \in \Gamma
\end{alignat*}
Then I began to proof as below:

Assuredly, let $(\gamma_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $\Gamma$ such that $\gamma_n\rightarrow\gamma$ in $\Gamma$, what is true once $\Gamma$ is complete. Hence $\Phi(\gamma_n)\rightarrow\Phi(\gamma)$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\Phi(\gamma_n)$ is bounded. One wants to prove that, for every $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ the set
$$[\Phi\leq \lambda]:=\{\gamma\in \Gamma: \Phi(\gamma)\leq \lambda\}\; \text{is closed.}$$
Indeed, let $(\gamma_n)$ be a sequence of functions in $[\Phi\leq \lambda]$, then
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\Phi(\gamma_n)&\leq \lim_{n\to \infty}\lambda=\lambda\\
\Phi(\gamma)=\Phi(\lim_{n \to \infty}\gamma_n)&\leq \lambda
\end{align*}
Therefore, $[\Phi\leq \lambda]$ is closed, which means that $\Phi$ is l.s.f.

**DOUBT:** Would someone tell me if my proof is right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you clarify the definition of $\Phi$, I mean is it a map with values in $Y^*$ or is it perhaps like you say a functional, i.e. a map to $\mathbb{R}$? In every case it does not make sense to write $J(\gamma(t))$ since $J\in Y$ and $\gamma$ takes also values in $Y$. Your proof is wrong, because you need to show that you are allowed to "pull out" the limit, but this can be done only for continuous mappings.

Comment: @Proxava First of all, I apologize for my late answer. You're right, I forgot to mention that $J$ restricted to $(Y, \|.\|)$ is continuous. I'll add in the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comment, your proof is wrong, because you don't know yet if $\Phi$ is continuous, hence you cannot pull limits in or out just now.

Instead consider the following hints:

1. Write $\Phi(\gamma)=\Phi(\gamma-\gamma_n)+\Phi(\gamma_n)$ and use a simple $\varepsilon$-limit argument.
2. We are only interested in $J$ restricted to $Y$, what can you say about a continuous linear map?
3. Deduce the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try.